# Why does jQuery class selector only return one element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

There are multiple divs with the class in the document.

As seen in the console, `document.getElementsByClassName` produces:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('current-pad-o')
HTMLCollection (2) = $8
0 <div class="red current-pad-o"> first value </div>
1 <div class="red current-pad-o"> second value </div>
```

and jquery, with the same class selector produces:

```
$('.current-pad-o')
// (the first div only - no collection)
<div class="red current-pad-o"> first value </div>
```

I would expect a collection from the jquery statement also. These were output in both Safari and Firefox.

According to the [jQuery Class Selector documentation](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/), the second selector ***Selects all elements with the given class***.

Why does jquery only return one, instead of a collection?

Comment: seems like the `document.getElementsByClassName` is returning the wrong thing!! That second div doesn NOT include the class `current-pad-o`

Comment: I am willing to bet it ain't jQuery, I am willing to bet what you think is jQuery is the debugger's shortcut for document.querySelector

Comment: But that's not the same class selector - one is `current-pad-o` and the other one is `currtrip-pad-o`.  They are different.

Comment: Question was edited. The jQuery selector works with the updated example.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that reproduces issue

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You do not have jQuery, you are using the debugger's shortcut for `document.querySelector()`. If you would use `$$('.current-pad-o')`, you would get all of them.

Too verify that you are not using jQuery, type the following into the command line:

```
console.log($)
```

For querySelector, you are going to see this:

```
function $(selector, [startNode]) { [Command Line API] }
```

For jQuery, you would see this:

```
function (a,b){return new n.fn.init(a,b)}
```

Reference: [console expressions](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/expressions)

Comment: This is what happens when one 'assumes'.  You hit the nail on the head. `console.log($) = undefined`

Comment: Yes it is undefined, but you can type $ onto console an it will display it as "native code" if jquery isnt there already.